# "Model.member" and "Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.member)" are different

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I refresh a page every 10 seconds with sending a form. I set the values for my model on HttpPost. For some reason `@Model.expression` shows the correct data, but `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.expression)` is always the same (it has the value that it got on the first, get request). Shouldn't they point to the same thing?

Here's my view:

```
@model vocab_2.Models.TrainingVM

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { name = "trainingForm", id = "trainingForm" }))
{
    <h1>@Model.expression</h1>

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.expression)

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.usersguess, new { Value = "" })

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.meaning, new { id="meaning" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924662/mvc2-textboxfor-value-not-updating-after-submit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the view data is passed back to the view and used to populate the fields regardless of what's in the model. Clear the view data before returning the form (this will however "reset" the form!):

```
ModelState.Clear();
return View();
```